# How to add video player for desktop (macOS and Windows) to a flutter

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-desktop

I need to make a program with a video player that will be supported everywhere. I use the video_player library, but it's only for iOS and Android, and I need and for macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for video player plugin on Windows, MacOS or linux as of now. Hopefully flutter team might add this feature by the end of this year.